# Modifying member of struct that is of int type error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, int, c-strings

In the code below, I am trying to access a member of the reference array of structs and shift it in the array index.
An  `invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]` error occurs when accessing the structure, as the reference to the index seems to be read as an indication of a cstring. 
How can I access the struct member in this context? What is wrong?

```
void removeSong (Song songList[], int& size){
    int indexRem;
    int i;
    cout << "Input index to remove" << endl;
    cin >> indexRem;

//Error checking for correct index( 0 and 1 less than count) needed

    for( i = indexRem; i < size; i++){
        songList[i] = songList[i+1];
    }

    strcpy(songList[i].title, songList[i+1].title);
    strcpy(songList[i].artist, songList[i+1].artist);
    strcpy(songList[i].album, songList[i+1].album);
    strcpy(songList[i].min, songList[i+1].min);
    strcpy(songList[i].sec, songList[i+1].sec);

    size--;
}
```

Edit: This question draws an incorrect relationship with c-strings. The issue is improper use of the strcpy function.

Comment: As for the error, *where* do you get it, on which line? And what does the structure look like?

Comment: Any reason why you simply couldn't use `std::vector<Song>` and additionally `std::string` instead of char arrays?

Comment: The error occurs at `strcpy(songList[i].min, songList[i+1].min);
    strcpy(songList[i].sec, songList[i+1].sec);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is for a course, and the string data type is disallowed.

Comment: @0x1000001 - 1) Get another course that actually teaches C++ instead of `C`.  2) What is the value of `i` on the last iteration of that loop?  Won't `[i+1]` be out-of-bounds of the array?  3) If item 2) is true, a `vector` would have shown you the error immediately.

Comment: You do know what the [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) function does? It copies a C-style ***string***. It does not copy integers. Try assignment.

Comment: Though I don't see a need for the separate copying of the structure member, try removing it and see if the structures are copied correctly in the loop anyway.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The goal is to shift down (towards zero) in the index. Is that assignment not accomplishing the goal?

Comment: @0x1000001 You didn't answer the question posed.  Say you have an array of 10 items, and `size == 10`.  On the last iteration, `i` will be 9, thus `Song[i+1]` is the same as `Song[10]` which is out-of-bounds.  It is the last iteration of the loop that you should be concerned with.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How do you shift items in the index then, as`i+1` creates an out of bounds scenario?

Comment: @0x1000001 What did you propose to replace the last entry with if you're shifting things down?  A blank struct?  The obvious thing to do is to loop to `size-1`, but the question on what that last entry becomes is one you should have considered.  Arrays cannot be resized, so there is no concept of erasing an element (as opposed to a `std::vector`, which can change the number of elements).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Would it be a good practice to preset the last object in the array to a null value to avoid the size issue?

Comment: Arrays cannot be resized.  It is a design decision you (or your teacher) has to make as to how to denote a blank `Song` item.  The whole thing was going to be a mess due to the misnomer that you're "removing" anything from an array, when actually you cannot remove things from an array, only simulate removing items by replacing items with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without at least seeing the `Song` structure definition, all I can assume is that at least one of it's members is of type `int`. The `strcpy` function is *only* necessary for C-strings (variables of type `const char*`), so you would be getting an error if you tried to use it for an `int`.

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks.